# Camel as an HTTP Proxy to a REST service - How to route paths and parameters?

Tags: rest, servlets, proxy, apache-camel

I am trying to use Apache Camel as an HTTP proxy to a REST service, performing some auth in the middle, and have a route which looks like this (auth removed for testing purposes):

```
from("servlet:apiwrapper?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http://HOST/BASEPATH?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

When accessing the Camel Servlet path like so:

```
http://CAMELHOST/apiwrapper/node
http://CAMELHOST/apiwrapper/node/stuff/blah?etc=t
```

And so on... I want to route these through to:

```
http://HOST/BASEPATH/node
http://HOST/BASEPATH/node/stuff/blah?etc=t
```

But my current route configuration just sends the requests to

```
http://HOST/BASEPATH
```

Without appending any of the path/url params I need appended. If I turn off bridgeEndpoint, then I just get errors thrown when the route hits the .to(HTTP) part.

How can I configure this route to map those through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I couldn't figure out an easy way to do this in config, so I added a bean between the input and the end of the route at the http endpoint that did some transformation and added basic auth, which looked like this:

```
  // Get all of the request path, including url params, after the context path of this camel app
  HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_SERVLET_REQUEST, HttpServletRequest.class);
  // Use the code below to get the request path instead of .getPathInfo(), as getPathInfo ignores url params
  String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());

  // Override the dummy host with the wrapped host
  exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, "http://baseurl");
  // Override the path that was in the exchange before
  exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, path);
  // Finally override the request params
  exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, request.getQueryString());

  // Set basic auth headers
  String basicAuth = String.format("%s:%s", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
  StringBuilder authHeader = new StringBuilder("Basic ");
  authHeader.append(Base64.encodeBase64String(basicAuth.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)));
  exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", authHeader.toString());
```

My route then looked like this, with a dummyhost and params:

```
from("servlet:apiwrapper?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("bean:httpHeaderSetter?method=setHttpHeaders")
.to("http://HOST/BASEPATH?throwExceptionOnFailure=false&amp;httpClient.authenticationPreemptive=true");
```